# AngularJS animation directive chain

Tags: angularjs, animation

I'm currently learning AngularJS and trying to create two directives.
Those directives allows me to animate images, respectively: 
rollImageIn resizes the image from 0 to 300px
rollImageOut resizes the image from 300px to 0px.

I would like to trigger the second directive when the first one is complete.

Here's my directives:
https://gist.github.com/egavard/f9cd6b6faf140fb77f130c4ca98cc1be

And here's my template:
https://gist.github.com/egavard/923cc37b0240baaa2d5a1ff5608e10d4

I was able to go over this problem by pasting the second animation in the first animation callback but I would like to create simple and reusable directives.

Does someone have an idea of what I've mistaken ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some mistakes here:

- First of all, invalid $compile call:

`$compile(element)(scope)`

- Then, the doc recommands to use .done() callback instead of then().

```js
    .done( function(){
     element.attr('roll-image-out', '{duration:'+rollOutDuration+', delay: '+rollOutDelay+', nextStep: '+nextStep+'}');
     element.removeAttr('roll-image-in');
     $compile(element)(scope);
    });
```

It's now working correctly.